# Way to implementing Search functinality on a Window

Tags: c#, wpf, search, window, string-search

I am working on a (WPF + C#) application. I have to implement search functionality. It will allow to search all the occurrences of a particular string on the specific part of Window. What can be the best way to do this?

Comment: Aren't you using a textbox to get the input? where actually is the string on which the search is to be made?

Comment: Do you want to iterate over a set of controls and check their content for this a particular string? Content can be anything so hard to make general. Do you have a VM which you could search instead?

Comment: @Veer: I am using TextBox, TextBlock, ComboBox, etc. to display strings and i need to search occurrence of particular string into them and highlight the occurrence.

Comment: @Wallstreet Programmer: Yes, the same way. In my case Content I am searching will be string only.

Answer (score 2):

Viky,

I hope I got you properly. You can take a look on what [Kent Boogaart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5380/kent-boogaart) has: [Search and Highlight Text in an Arbitrary Visual Tree](http://kentb.blogspot.com/2009/06/search-and-highlight-text-in-arbitrary.html):

[image]

Comment: thanks for the reply its really helpful, but my window can contain other controls as well. like TextBox, ComboBox, i need to search Text in them also. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Viky, as long as it's in the visual tree it should work (TextBoxes should work). As for the ComboBox... it's little trickier, because items in the drop down list are in popup's visual tree. In that case you would probably have to customize Kent's algorithm to check against "known" exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using [ICollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icollectionview.aspx) for filtering. [Here is an example](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/11/22/icollectionview-explained/).